# Convergence of partial sums of independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

For a sequence $(X_i)_{i\geqslant 1}   $ of independent random variables with zero means, if $d_{n,r}=\frac{(\sum_{i=1}^nEX_i^2)^\frac{1}{2}}{(\sum_{i=1}^nE|X_i|^{2+r})^\frac{1}{2+r}}\rightarrow\infty$ for some $0<r\leq1$, then 
$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2}{\sum_{i=1}^nEX_i^2}\rightarrow1\mbox{ in   probability} .$$ I tried to prove this by Chebyshev inequality and $C_r$ inequality:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&P\left(\bigg|\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2-\sum_{i=1}^nEX_i^2}{\sum_{i=1}^nEX_i^2}\bigg|>\epsilon\right)\\
&\leq\frac{E|\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2-\sum_{i=1}^nEX_i^2|}{\epsilon\sum_{i=1}^nEX_i^2}\\
&\leq\frac{\bigg(E|\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2-\sum_{i=1}^nEX_i^2|^\frac{2+r}{2}\bigg)^\frac{2}{2+r}}{\epsilon\sum_{i=1}^nEX_i^2}\\
&\leq\frac{n^\frac{r}{2+r}\bigg(E\sum_{i=1}^n|X_i^2-EX_i^2|^\frac{2+r}{2}\bigg)^\frac{2}{2+r}}{\epsilon\sum_{i=1}^nEX_i^2}\\
&\leq\frac{2n^\frac{r}{2+r}\bigg(E\sum_{i=1}^n|X_i|^{2+r}\bigg)^\frac{2}{2+r}}{\epsilon\sum_{i=1}^nEX_i^2}\\
&=\frac{2n^\frac{r}{2+r}}{\epsilon d_{n,r}}.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
However, by using the $C_r$ inequality, $n$ appears in the nominator. How to prove the above convergence? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Von Bahr-Esseen's inequality states that for any $p\in (1,2)$, there exists a constant $C_p$ such that for any independent sequence of random variables $\left(Y_i\right)_{i=1}^\infty  $, 
$$\mathbb E\left\lvert\sum_{i=1}^n    Y_i\right\rvert^p   \leqslant C_p\sum_{i=1}^n   \mathbb E\left\lvert Y_i\right\rvert^p .$$
Apply this to $Y_i=X_i^2-\mathbb E\left[X_i^2\right]$ and $p=(r+2)/2$ to get that the sequence  $\left( \left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i^2-\mathbb E\left[X_i^2\right]    \right) /\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb E\left[X_i^2\right]          \right)_{n\geqslant 1}        $  goes to zero in $\mathbb L^{(r+2)/2}$.

Note also that the fact that the $X_i$ are centered is not used.